# html - relative layout with css side by side

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

My purpose is show a original canvas with 400x400 (canvas1), and use a small canvas 50x50 (canvas2) to select a region, then show amplified result to canvas 200x200 (canvas3). I wish canvas2 will move with mouse but canvas3 keep at right side of canvas1.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <head>
  <style>
  .container {
position: relative;
border: 1px solid black;
  }
.inner {
    border:1px solid red;
    pointer-events: none;
    position: absolute;
}
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <canvas id="canvas1" width="400" height="400" style="border:1px solid red;" onmousemove="onMouseMove(event,this);"></canvas>
    <div id="glass" class="inner">
        <canvas class="inner" id="canvas2" width=50 height=50 ></canvas>
        <div class="inner" style="top: 25px; left: 0px; width: 50px;"/>
        <div class="inner" style="top: -25px; left: 25px; height: 50px;"/>
    </div>
    <div id="zoomer" class="container">
        <canvas id="canvas3" class="inner" width=200 height=200 ></canvas>
        <div class="inner" style="top: 100px; left: 0px; width: 200px;"/>
        <div class="inner" style="top: -100px; left: 100px; height: 200px;"/>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
        <input id="browser" type='file' ></input>
    </div>

    <script>
    var glass = document.getElementById('glass');
    var canvas2 = document.getElementById('canvas2');
    var w = canvas2.width;
    var h = canvas2.height; 

    function onMouseMove(event,thiz) {
       var x = event.offsetX;
        var y = event.offsetY;
        glass.style.left = (x - w/2) + 'px';
        glass.style.top = (y - h/2) + 'px';
    }
   </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

But current result is:

1. canvas2 and canvas3 will move together if mouse move.
2. The choose file button overlapped with canvas 3.

I wish only canvas2 (and the crosshair lines) move with mouse but keep canvas1,canvas3 and chosse file button statically side by side.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

1. The div statement is not correct.
2. Use inline-block display mode.

With below html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <head>
  <style>
  .container {
display: inline-block;
vertical-align: top;
position: relative;
border: 1px solid black;
  }
.inner {
    border:1px solid red;
    pointer-events: none;
    position: absolute;
}
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <canvas id="canvas1" width="400" height="400" style="border:1px solid red;" onmousemove="onMouseMove(event,this);"></canvas>
    <div id="glass" class="inner">
        <canvas class="inner" id="canvas2" width=50 height=50 ></canvas>
        <div class="inner" style="top: 25px; left: 0px; width: 50px;"></div>
        <div class="inner" style="top: 0px; left: 25px; height: 50px;"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="zoomer" class="container">
        <canvas id="canvas3" class="inner" width=200 height=200 ></canvas>
        <div class="inner" style="top: 100px; left: 0px; width: 200px;"></div>
        <div class="inner" style="top: 0px; left: 100px; height: 200px;"></div>
    </div>
    <input id="browser" type='file' ></input>

    <script>
    var glass = document.getElementById('glass');
    var canvas2 = document.getElementById('canvas2');
    var w = canvas2.width;
    var h = canvas2.height; 

    function onMouseMove(event,thiz) {
       var x = event.offsetX;
        var y = event.offsetY;
        glass.style.left = (x - w/2) + 'px';
        glass.style.top = (y - h/2) + 'px';
    }
   </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

The result is below:
[image]